# Prove that the closed ball $\overline{B}(0,1) \subseteq \mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ can't be covered by countably-many compact sets.

Tags: real-analysis

For $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ the space of continuous functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, I'm asked to prove that $\overline{B}(0,1) = \{ f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R}) : ||f||_\infty \leqslant 1 \}$ can't be covered by countably-many compact sets in $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. But I'm not sure where to even begin. Any ideas on how to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually holds in general for infinite-dimensional Banach Spaces, such as $\mathcal{C}([0, 1], \Bbb{R})$.

Suppose $X$ is a Banach Space. If $X$ is covered by countably many compact sets $(K_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$, then because each set is closed, the Baire Category Theorem implies that at least one of the $K_i$s has a non-empty interior. That is, there exists some closed ball $x + rB_X \subseteq K_i$, where $r$ is some positive real number.
But then, this implies,
$$B_X \subseteq \frac{1}{r}(-x + K_i),$$
which is compact, hence $B_X$ is compact. A compact closed unit ball implies that $X$ is finite-dimensional. Thus, if $X$ is infinite-dimensional, no such compact sets can exist.

Comment: What do you mean by $x+rB_X$? Do you mean a closed ball $B_X = (a,\varrho)$ in $X$ and $x+rB_X = B(x+a, r\varrho)$?

Comment: $B_X$ refers to the closed unit ball centred at the origin, i.e. $B[0; 1]$, i.e. $\{x \in X : \|x\| \le 1\}$. The set $x + rB_X$ (where $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ are fixed) refers to the set of points that have the form $x + ru$ where $u \in B_X$. That is to say, $x + rB_X$ is the ball of radius $r$, centred at $x$, i.e. $B[x; r]$, i.e. $\{y \in X : \|y - x\| \le r\}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I suspected that the BCT was a possible approach, but didn't put much thought into it. It's quite an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $C_n$ is compact. Then the $C_n$'s are equicontinuous; choose the $\delta_n$ as in the definition of equicontinuity of $C_n$. It is easy to construct a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [-1, 1]$ whose graph has gradient greater than $\frac{1}{\delta_n}$ at $1/n$; the graph merely has to consist of countably many tents next to each other of required steepness. To make $f$ continuous just require that the tent width tends to $0$. Then $f\notin \bigcup\limits_n C_n$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a great idea! Thanks.

Comment: The delta_n’s need to correspond to some episllon_n though. And the epsillon_n needs to tend to 0. And the n’th tent then needs to be at least epsilon_n high... I’ll fill in the details tomorrow maybe