# continuous functions of finite dimension banach spaces in infinite dimension banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I have the following problem but I am not sure how to proceed.
I that could suppose that there is at least one continuous function, but afterwards I don't know how to continue.

Prove that there is no continuous function of a finite dimension Banach X space over an infinite dimension Banach Y space.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the balls $nB_X$ in $X$, centred at $0$, radius $n$. Note that these sets are compact and union to give $X$. If we have a continuous surjective function $f : X \to Y$, then $f(nB_X)$ are compact and union to give $Y$. But [according to my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750551/prove-that-the-closed-ball-overlineb0-1-subseteq-mathcalc0-1-math/3750579#3750579), this would imply $Y$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: thanks for the idea, in fact something like that I was thinking and I came to a similar conclusion where I needed the function f to be surjective, but then in the problem you would have to ask that there is no continuous surjective function or why you use surjectivity  ?

Comment: @user790915 I honestly thought by "over an infinite dimensional space $Y$", you meant "onto an infinite dimensional space $Y$", i.e. a surjective map. If you drop this assumption, then the result is false. Quick counterexample: the zero map.

Comment: ooh thanks so much for the counterexample and suggestion.  Now the idea of ​​how to solve the exercise is much clearer.

Comment: @user790915 Out of curiosity, was surjectivity part of the exercise after all?

Comment: yes, it was part of the problem after all and with the counterexample you gave me it is quite clear that it does have to be part of the exercise.